# Oracle: Choose user-selected column in procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a procedure that can take a column name as an input parameter and select that column from a table.

I know you can do this in a regular query by simply creating a string variable and referencing the column like such:

```
DEFINE mycol = 'column1'

SELECT a.&mycol FROM table1 a
```

This does however not work within a procedure. Variables in procedures don't appear to be able to be referenced by the '&' symbol, and as such when I attempt to pull a column using an input parameter it tells me that it's an invalid identifier.

Searching around on the internet, I can't find an example of someone doing this without dynamic SQL, when inside a proc. I would prefer not to use dynamic SQL if possible.

Does anyone know a workaround for this, or is dynamic SQL required in procs for this to occur?

Cheers,

Ollie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SQL in named block is inevitable as ampersand construct are not compliant with SQL standard. It's only feature of SQL Plus engine.

Comment: Fair enough. Real shame - seems like something that would be very handy to be able to do!

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the scenarios as described.

```
CREATE TABLE SCOTT.COLUMN_LIST
(
  COLUMN_ID             NUMBER,
  COLUMN_NAME        VARCHAR2(200),
  TABLE_NAME           VARCHAR2(50 )
);

Insert into SCOTT.COLUMN_LIST
   (COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME)
 Values
   (1, 'DEPTNO', 'DEPT');
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE SCOTT.TEST1
(
  A  VARCHAR2(300 BYTE)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1
IS
v_Select_Column  VARCHAR2(200);
v_Table_Name VARCHAR2(50 );
V_SQL               VARCHAR2(300);

BEGIN

SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME 
INTO v_Select_Column,v_Table_Name
FROM COLUMN_LIST
WHERE COLUMN_ID=1;

V_SQL:= 'SELECT '||v_Select_Column|| 
               ' FROM '||v_Table_Name;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL;

INSERT INTO TEST1 values(V_SQL);
COMMIT;

END PROC1;
/
```

Please test at your end. You can see the output on test1 table.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using dynamic SQL (it will complicate my code a fair bit) but it looks like it's unavoidable. Thanks for your help!